# Database Password problem when using GIT to manage project that uses Spring to initiate Datasource

Tags: java, git, xml, spring, jdbc

I use Spring Framework to code my Web Service, using Dependency injection to inject a DataSource bean into the DAO bean that will be used by the Web Service. I have all the database properties(Url, Password, Username, the stuff I don't want people to see) **written in the DataSource Bean XML**!

I have git setup to commit my entire project....Including my DataSource Bean XML which has my password written in plain text. I thought of using the .gitignore but the Bean XML is a crucial component in my Web Service project and it shouldn't be ignored. But I also don't want the world to see my password.

How do I commit my bean files without showing the world my password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything you put into the Spring XML is static and compiled into the binary. If there is some information which can change, it is always a good idea to externalize it into a properties file. Spring can read the properties file and then use the values as inputs to its beans.

You need to use a concept called the property placeholder to inject these properties. First, create a properties file, say, `MyApp.properties` and place it into a known directory, say, `/settings/MyApp`. The contents of the file will be in the format:

```
databaseUsername=USER
databasePassword=PWD
property3=value3
property4=value4
...
```

In your Spring XML, add the following tag:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///settings/MyApp/MyApp.properties"/>
```

Now, you can simply use these external properties in your spring objects:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="...">
    <property name="username" value="${databaseUsername}">
    <property name="password" value="${databasePassword}">
</bean
```

Now you can safely check in your Spring XML (but not `MyApp.properties`) and make sure that other users have their own `MyApp.properties` at the configured location.

There are other things you can do to make the property file lookup more dynamic. See this link for more details:

[6 Tips for Managing Property Files with Spring](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/)